# Tips for alleviating soreness?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, muay-thai, boxing, kickboxing, mixed-martial-arts

I know this has been asked before by the suggested Q&A after I typed in the question, but this is a bit different in that after kickboxing/Muay Thai/boxing/sparring I'm very rarely if ever sore but after BJJ (especially when live rolling after instruction is involved) I can hardly move. More often than not while I don't get very many advantageous positions I also don't get tapped very often either. My cardio honestly isn't that great being a bigger fighter (6 foot tall, 250 pounds, but working on reducing body fat percentage) but this is a kind of sore I only feel after doing high intensity interval training. Could it be something I'm doing wrong not being a very good ground fighter or is it just because I'm utilizing all my muscle groups and strength at once? Is there a way besides cold/hot soak, stretching, and fish oil to reduce soreness? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of soreness? Is it a lactic acid build up soreness? Or is is like you've lifted heaps of weights and given your muscles a working over type of soreness? One is a dull tired ache that affects entire sections of your body, the other is sharper and more localised (the two can be combined as well).

Comment: It's like if I went to the gym and worked on nothing but legs for 2 hours kind of sore. That's my main ache. The other is more like "worked me good yesterday, here's a reminder" and just a dull ache on my upper body, specifically my lats and even my neck muscles, front and back

Comment: Are you new to BJJ?

Comment: I'm new to BJJ in that I haven't done it in well over a decade, focused more on Muay Thai and Taekwondo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-massage is trending as a main way to reduce soreness generated by hard muscle training.

You can do it with your own hands and fingers or by the aid of a foam roller or a tennis ball. I'll recommend you to check this videos.

- [How to Get Rid of Muscle Soreness, Aches + Pains](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSulYGQXpv4)
- [3 Unique Boxing Drills Using a Tennis Ball](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQ4dkJ9afz0)

Enough sleeping (min 7:30 h) and eating should also help. Don't stop trainning hard, just do it smartly.

Hope this helps you Matt!

PS: I'm also a tall guy, and as one I can tell you that in general, if muscle force exercises are done properly we'll exert a little more effort in comparisson to shorter individuals because of length and weight of the body, also with increased gains in muscle growth, keeping everything always in proportion. This is a matter of proportions and physics.

Comment: Foam roller, so like a trigger point then? Nice. Got my girlfriend one of those. It's pink but who cares? Lol

Comment: Personal experience, foam rollers are amazing.

Answer (score 1):

I get sore muscles all the time.

Remember to get enough rest between training. I usually rest for an entire day, making sure I get enough sleep before my next workout.

I have heard before about eating egg whites and drinking whey protein shakes help with muscle repair, but I have yet to try it.

What really helps is a good massage on the sore area before sleep, and the muscle should heal the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of water - both before and after practice. Its a simple answer, but one that works. 
Water and rolling out the muscles.